# Is it possible to run the deployment phase even when a Travis build fail?

Tags: travis-ci

Is it possible to run the deployment phase in Travis CI even when the build is reporting a failure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Deployment does not happen if the `script` fails.

If you want to execute a block of code regardless of the result, use `after_script` and a custom script.

https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/custom/ describes how to deploy with `after_success`, but the idea is the same.

Comment: But, deploying using `after_success` will deploy from any branch, correct?