# Travis CI skip test and deploy

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci, continuous-deployment

My Travis tests fail, but I still want to deploy the app. Is it possible to skip the testing phase in Travis and continue to the deployment?

Comment: Why do you want to deploy broken code? At that point, why bother with CI at all?

Comment: @jonrsharpe the fact that tests don't pass, does not necessarily mean the code is broken, does it?

Comment: Some of my tests depend on third-party servers that may be unavailable from time to time

Comment: And how do you distinguish between tests failing because those services are unavailable and because the code is broken? Maybe that would point you towards a solution. Or perhaps your tests are too closely coupled to those services?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I understand that a good solution would be to mock the dependencies in the test environment. But it's an additional effort that I have no time for. It is not the point of the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to run the deployment phase even when a Travis build fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38916480/is-it-possible-to-run-the-deployment-phase-even-when-a-travis-build-fail)

Answer (score 16):

You can add a `script` with a `echo` to your `.travis.yml` file.

This will force Travis to run your script message instead of running tests automatically.

```
script:
- echo "skipping tests"
```

Comment: But, where you can put this script?

Comment: what do you mean? you add it in your `.travis.yml`

Answer (score 1):

According to the official documentation, the way to do this is to put :

```
install: true
```

Here it is : https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#skipping-the-installation-step

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to skip tests but still build, you can invoke xcode build without the test option.

```
script:
- set -o pipefail
- xcodebuild -workspace YourWorkspace.xcworkspace -scheme YourScheme -destination platform\=yourDestinationPlatform build | xcpretty
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this line to your `.travis.yml` file.

`script: echo "Success!"`